# Get a Dictionary by applying function to pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to apply a function to a dataframe and receive a single dictionary as a result. pandas.apply gives me a Series of dicts, and so currently I have to combine keys from each. I'll use an example to illustrate.

I have a pandas dataframe like so.

```
In [20]: df
Out[20]:
          0  1
0  2.025745  a
1 -1.840914  b
2 -0.428811  c
3  0.718237  d
4  0.079593  e
```

I have some function that returns a dictionary. For this example I'm using a toy lambda function `lambda x: {x: ord(x)}` that returns a dictionary.

```
In [22]: what_i_get = df[1].apply(lambda x: {x: ord(x)})
In [23]: what_i_get
Out[23]:
0     {'a': 97}
1     {'b': 98}
2     {'c': 99}
3    {'d': 100}
4    {'e': 101}
Name: 1
```

apply() gives me a series of dictionaries, but what I want is a single dictionary.

I could create it with something like this:

```
In [41]: what_i_want = {}
In [42]: for elem in what_i_get:
   ....:    for k,v in elem.iteritems():
   ....:        what_i_want[k] = v
   ....:

In [43]: what_i_want
Out[43]: {'a': 97, 'b': 98, 'c': 99, 'd': 100, 'e': 101}
```

But it seems I should be able to get what I want more directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of returning a dict from your function, just return the mapped value, then create one dict outside the mapping operation:

```
>>> d
   Stuff
0     a
1     b
2     c
3     d
>>> dict(zip(d.Stuff, d.Stuff.map(ord)))
{'a': 97, 'b': 98, 'c': 99, 'd': 100}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had overlooked `map` completely, and my rewritten function is much cleaner now.

Answer (score 1):

Cutting out the items() middle-man:

```
what_i_want = {}
for elem in what_i_get:
    what_i_want.update(elem)
```

Comment: Ah, thanks, but that part was illustrative only. I don't want to have to compute the Series what_i_get in order to get the dictionary what_i_want.